# Directory rules for folders outside of DocumentRoot

Tags: apache

Do I need to specify a  rule for folders in an upper level of the provided path in DocumentRoot?

Simplifying the case, I have this directories:

```
/project1/public
/project1/private
```

And then in the config files:

```
DocumentRoot /project1/public

<Directory /project1/>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Do I need to specify a `<Directory /project1/private/>` rule? Could this folder be accessed from somewhere else I'm not realizing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule is applied to the named file-system directory, sub-directories, and their contents. Therefore, you don't need to specify a rule for `<Directory /project1/private/>`